# How to avoid my android application to be shown in the "recent apps" list?

Tags: java, android

I developed an android application and I want to avoid it to be shown in the "recent apps" list.

Is it posssible to do that in my code?If yes, How to do that?

[image]

Comment: What was the purpose of the image?

Comment: @Squonk to show an example of apps list. to make my question more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I will accept your answer and also (+1) in 6 min.

Answer (score 2):

place this line in your application manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
</activity>

<activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    </activity>
```

.
.
.
.

place this tag in side activity tag, which activity you have to hide from recent, place this tag to that activity.